# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric but i already converted the string into int

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports, pos, receipt

I don't know what the problem is, because I've converted it to int already.

I commented in my code where the error occurs please help me it's for my final research and this is for printing the receipt if you have any suggestion on how to print a receipt please comment it, I would really appreciate it - thank you.

This is my code:

```
public void salessave()
{
    string tot = ttotaltxt.Text;
    string pay = amounttxt.Text;
    string bal = changetxt.Text;
    string discount = discountttxt.Text;

    string sql1;
    string sql2;

    sql1 = "insert into SSales (subtotal, pay, balance, discount) values (@subtotal, @pay, @balance, @discount) select @@identity; ";

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtotal", tot);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pay", pay);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", bal);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", discount);

    // this is where the error occurs
    int lastinserid = int.Parse(cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); 

    string prodname;
    int price = 0;
    int qty = 0;
    decimal total = 0;
    decimal dis = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        prodname = dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        price = int.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
        qty = int.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        total = decimal.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
        dis = decimal.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value.ToString());

        sql2 = "insert into sales_productss (sales_id, ProductName, Price, Quantity, Discount, Total) values (@sales_id, @ProductName, @Price, @Quantity, @Discount, @Total)";

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sales_id", lastinserid);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", prodname);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", price);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", qty);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", dis);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", total);

        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    printing p = new printing();
    p.SalesID = lastinserid;
    p.Show();

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You're not in your first statement. You define *all* your variables as `string`s (clearly not an `int`) and you use `AddWithValue` to pass them; which will likely send them as a `nvarchar`. 1. Don't define all your variables as a `string`, use appropriate data types. 2. [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: im only having problems at int lastinserid = int.Parse(cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

Comment: Try also adding `set nocount on; ` to the beginning your first SQL statement, otherwise the insert statement returns a rowcount of 1 but without any results.

Comment: i replace @@IDENTITY with SCOPE_IDENTITY() but its still said error converting nvarchar to int in here  int lastinserid = int.Parse(cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

Comment: @Angel it wasnt the cause of the problem, it was just another issue in the code. if it was the problem marc would have probably posted an answer, not a comment

Comment: *but i already converted the string into int* where in the code did you do this?

Comment: For the first command you are not converting/parsing the numbers. Also `int lastinserid = int.Parse(cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());` is just silly, why don't you just cast it `int lastinserid = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: it still giving me the same error